# How to convert data from website to google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

I want to import some data from a website to my google sheet. I’m most interested in the first section “Totals”.
I have tried typing this in my google sheet: `=IMPORTHTML(“BC Copenhagen-Teamstats - Basketligaen 2”,"table", 1)`
But the number 2, seems to be a problem, Idk why thought.

I have also experimented with this:
`=IMPORTXML(“https://basketligaen.dk/bc-copenhagen-teamstats/“,”//*[@id=‘hs-container’]/div/div/div/div/div[2]”)`
However, it can’t find the data

Should I maybe use a service like Make or Zapier? However, I'm not sure how.

Website: BC Copenhagen-Teamstats - Basketligaen

Answer (score 1):

Google sheets' `IMPORTXML` does not support the scraping of JavaScript elements:

[image]

Comment: Starting to think we need a master question for this and duplicate them all...

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015233/5632629