# IMPORTXML and right XPath from Bloomberg price

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get price from mutual-fund from the Bloomberg website.
I have tried to use the ImportXML function in Google sheets, put in the Bloomberg link and copy the Full XPath but it always return with the #N/A.

This is my function:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/KAUGVAA:LX","/html/body/div[6]/div/div/section/section[1]/div/div[2]/section[1]/section/section/section/div[1]/span[1]")
```

This is the Bloomberg link:
https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/KAUGVAA:LX?leadSource=uverify%20wall

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

if all you are getting is `#N/A` error you have 3 options before turning to a script

1. disable JavaScript. google sheets' IMPORT formulae do not support the reading of JS content/elements. after you disable JS on your URL and the element you wish to scrape is not present there is 99.9% certainty you can give up! if the stuff you seek is still there move to point 2...

   [image]
2. run an XML debugging formula to test what can be scrapped:

   ```
   =IMPORTXML("URL"; "//*")
   ```

   if the result is `#N/A` give up and move to point 3...
3. run a sourcecode debugging formula to test what else can be scrapped:

   ```
   =IMPORTDATA("URL")
   ```

   if the output is `#N/A` give up and move to the next point. if the output is any other kind of error try:

   ```
   =QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA("URL")); "where Col1 is not null"; )
   ```
4. at this stage open a google and try to find a different website that hosts the same data you want to get. then repeat steps 1-3. still no luck and your requirements are not that high? move to the next point...
5. go to google and search the URL. if there is a match try to check if there is a Cache:

   [image]

   take the URL and repeat steps 2-3. if this is not your thing or if luck left your life for good, move to point 6...

   ```
   =IMPORTXML("https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:aQET6JV0DywJ:https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/KAUGVAA:LX&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk", 
    "//div[@class='overviewRow__66339412a5']")
   ```

   [image]
6. give up or use a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping+google-apps-script)