# "Import internal error" - scraping data in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, import, google-sheets-formula

I used `IMPORTXML` in Sheets to pull website titles from several hundred sites. My initial pass worked but then I moved the data around a few times while cleaning and now most of the cells display

> import internal error.

I've tried refreshing the sheet and recopying the formula into the affected cells, but neither of these ideas worked.

I also previously converted URLs that were being scraped from hyperlinked text in another column to plain text, to reduce the number of formulas operating at one time. This did not work either -- the URLs being plain text wouldn't affect `IMPORTXML`, would it?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015233/5632629

Comment: thanks - the debugger (point 2 in what you linked) shows scraping still works, which isn't surprising as the formula is working for a couple rows atm. can't go through and disable JS manually for each website as there are so many. any further suggestions?

Comment: I ended up using this person's code https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/114124 works great!