# Google Sheets Import XML function to fetch data from Amazon used books side panel

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I am using the IMPORTXML function in Google sheets to get some product information for some books and it is working when I am accessing information from the main page (like price and title etc.) as shown below:

[image]

[image]

However I also want to fetch data for used books, which is available in a panel that opens on the right hand side, when I click the used books options which you can see below:

[image]

So when I copy the Xpath from from the price in this panel/section, the IMPORTXML function does not work.

[image]

I am assuming that this does not work because the panel on the right hand side has a different link to access it but I don't have HTML knowledge so I am not sure how to make this work.

Here is the link to this book that I have used in the example above:

Short Link: shorturl.at/AJLQ8
Full Link: [https://www.amazon.com/Ace-Data-Science-Interview-Questions/dp/0578973839/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=1KPOOAYSZZTJ8&keywords=it+textbook&qid=1669937052&sprefix=it+textbook%2Caps%2C372&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyOVlUN1k0N1JQQU9MJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMzgwMTY3MVE1S1kySEJHMjZaSiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMjU0MzE0MjkzREM3Q0RLSFpOQiZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0578973839)

I tried finding the address of that specific panel on the right but unfortunately didn't succeed.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015233/5632629

Answer (score -1):

As per checking on the website that you have provided, the data that you are trying to pull is a javascript-rendered webpage, even if you go directly to it's link address it will still render the main page and just pull out the modal using javascript: https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0578973839/ref=tmm_pap_used_olp_0?ie=UTF8&condition=used

[image]

Which is a **limitation of `IMPORTXML Function`** as stated in this article: [Limitations of IMPORTXML](https://nodatanobusiness.com/blog/a-user-friendly-alternative-to-importxml/#:%7E:text=The%20biggest%20limitations%20to%20IMPORTXML,every%20change%20to%20the%20Sheet.)

> Javascript-rendered websites are not supported: this automatically
> excludes a large amount of websites, as it is common for popular and
> large websites to be rendered in Javascript.

*Note: I am not affiliated with the website/reference, I just found it through research.*