# Webscrape specific information

Tags: excel, google-sheets, web, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape the 2 screenshot informations from the link below, but neither in google sheets or nor in excel I couldnt. Does anyone have any idea about it , appreciated. Thank you[image]
https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home/fly/flight-information/flight-status-results.html#/flight-status-results?method=byfn&date=01-15-2023&fn=887

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015233/5632629

Answer (score 2):

There may be no straightforward way to grab that information with a spreadsheet formula.

To understand why, see [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/115665/269219)

Comment: To understand the negative votes, see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/13045193)