# How do I pull website information (class within class within div within class within div) through google sheets?

Tags: html, google-sheets, web-scraping, https, google-sheets-formula

I'm creating a spreadsheet that pulls basic information from a website for an upcoming bicycle tour that I'm doing. In short, I'm trying to gather community names, locations, and contact information. I'm very new to this (as in a few hours) and can't seem to find specific formulas for access information under many different umbrellas of coding.

The source code reads:

```
<div class="clearfix"><div class="float-left"><h1 class="mb-1">Sustainable Ecovillage</h1><h2><small>Gasquet, California, United States</small></h2></div><ul class="text-right small text-muted float-right list-unstyled"><li><b>Updated on: </b>Oct 19, 2022 (about 1 month ago)</li><li><b>Created on: </b>Dec 26, 2008 (almost 14 years ago)</li></ul></div>
```

I'm trying to gather the community name (h1) in one cell, and location (h2) in another.

I'd also like to grab the website link if it exists:

```
<li><b>Website:</b> <a href="https://sustainableecovillage.com/" target="_blank">https://sustainableecovillage.com/</a></li>
```

As well as the Contact Name, Phone, and Address:

```
<ul class="card-body list-unstyled listing-status mb-0"><li><b>Status:</b> <span class="">Established (4+ adults, 2+ years)</span></li><li><b>Started Planning:</b> 2007</li><li><b>Started Living Together:</b> 2008</li><li><b>Visitors Accepted:</b> <span class="text-success">Yes</span></li><li><b>Open to New Members:</b> <span class="text-success">Yes</span></li><li class="text-center mt-2 mb-3"><small class="text-muted">Please read the details in <a href="#Membership">Membership</a> below before contacting this community.</small><a class="my-1 btn btn-block btn-warning" href="/directory/contact-a-community/?cmty=38947">Send Message</a></li><li>**<b>Website:</b> <a href="https://sustainableecovillage.com/" target="_blank">https://sustainableecovillage.com/</a>**</li><li><b>Business, Project, or Organization:</b> <a href="https://sustainableecovillage.com/" target="_blank">https://sustainableecovillage.com/</a></li><li><b>Contact Name:</b> Dan</li><li><b>Phone:</b> 707-954-7743</li><li><b>Community Address:</b><address>P O Box 246<br>Gasquet, California 95543<br>United States</address></li><li><h3 class="text-center"><a href="/community-bookstore/product/fic-membership/" target="_blank">FIC Membership</a></h3><div class="text-center mb-3"><a href="/community-bookstore/product/fic-membership/" target="_blank"><img id="fic-membership-badge" title="FIC Membership Badge" src="/wp-content/themes/fic-theme/img/membership-badge.png?v=1" alt="This Community is an FIC Member" class="img-fluid"></a></div></li><li><h3 class="text-center">Location</h3><img src="/wp-content/themes/fic-theme/img/directory-map-placeholder.png?v=1" alt="Directory Map Placeholder" class="img-fluid"></li></ul>
```

From my reaserch, it seems I should be able to simply put

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.ic.org/directory/sustainable-ecovillage/","//h1")`

However, it returns content is empty.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015233/5632629