# How to retrieve data to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've tried to get table's data from https://www.set.or.th/th/market/index/set/agro/agri
to Google Sheets

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.set.or.th/th/market/index/set/agro/agri","table",1)
```

Changing `list` to `table` and still unable to get the data.
My expected output in Sheets is

```
EE         bunch of numbers
GFPT       bunch of numbers
LEE        bunch of numbers
.          bunch of numbers
.          bunch of numbers
VPO        bunch of numbers
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015233/5632629

Comment: Lorena's answer provides details about this behavior, is that information helpful for you? See: [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

The content you're trying to extract, loads with JavaScript and `IMPORT` functions can’t extract content that loads with JavaScript. You can check this [article](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/import-social-media-statistics/#notWorking).

If you click on the ‘Lock’ icon beside the browser’s address bar, select ‘Site settings’ and set JavaScript to ‘Block’. Reload the page and as you can see in the screenshot below, the site needs JavaScript enabled to load certain content.

[image]